# Cartrige instances.yml file

Tags: tarantool, tarantool-cartridge

What do these fields mean, and what should I put there for my app?

```
cartridge:
    cluster_cookie: ""
    replication_connect_quorum: 1

cartridge.srv-1:
    workdir: dev/3301
    advertise_uri: localhost:3301
    http_port: 8081

------ stripped ------

cartridge-stateboard:
    workdir: ./dev/stateboard
    password: qwerty
    listen: 4401
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cartridge has 2 types of configuration:

- per-instance, meaning that the configuration can be only seen by the specific instance
- clusterwise, that is shared by all instances

What you have here in `instances.yml` file is the per-instance configuration. You'd want to use it for parameters that differ instance-by-instance. For example, listen ports, or the amount of memory a specific instance will get.

You can also see that the top-level section in the instances.yml contains app name and instance name separated by a dot. This is how an instance decides which part of this configuration to load. It will search itself in the top-level section and only load the relevant piece (in your example it's `cartridge.srv-1`). There is also a way to specify configuration for all instances of an app. In this case, omit the instance name (like `cartridge` in your example). Then, every instance of the app named `cartridge` will load those parameters as well.

As to what parameters can be specified, there are 3 types:

- All [box.cfg parameters](https://www.tarantool.io/en/doc/latest/reference/configuration/#box-cfg-params) such as `memtx_memory` or `wal_mode` are supported. You can pass them with their original name.
- Cartridge-specific parameters such as `http_port` or `advertise_uri`. You can find the list [here](https://www.tarantool.io/en/doc/latest/book/cartridge/cartridge_api/modules/cartridge.argparse/#cluster-opts).
- Custom parameters specific for your app. See this answer: [How I can to get custom options in the `init` function of the Tarantool Cartridge role?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62040869/how-i-can-to-get-custom-options-in-the-init-function-of-the-tarantool-cartridg)